# making a loop to find the nth term in fibonacci sequence

Tags: java, loops, sequence, fibonacci

I'm trying to write a program that can find the nth term in Fibonacci-type series (it has to be non-recursive, by the way). It has to be able to take any two numbers from the user, and use them as the first two terms.

For example, if the user inputs f1 = 2 and f2 = 3, then the series is 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, etc.

The user also is able to input which term they want to come up.

I've gotten most of the program done (I think), but I have two problems

1. When finding the nth term the programs has to count f1 and f2 as terms 1 and 2. i cannot get it to do this, it counts the 3rd number as the first one
2. The program prints out all the numbers up to the nth term, but I want it to only print out the nth term

I've been at this for a while now, I'm pretty new to Java, I took a intro class in it 2 years ago, now I'm in the next class up, having a little trouble, so any help would be appreciated!

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class fibs
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in); // readying keyboard for input
    int f1, f2, n, fib;
    System.out.println("Please enter a vaule for F(1):");
    f1 = keyboard.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Please enter a vaule for F(2):");
    f2 = keyboard.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Please enter a vaule for n :");
    n = keyboard.nextInt();

    if ((f1<0)||(f2<0)||(f1>1000)||(f2>1000)||(n<1))
    {
      System.out.println("Please try again");
      return;
    }
    else
    {
      int i;
      for (i=0; i<n; i++)
      {

        fib=f1+f2;
        f1=f2;
        f2=fib;
        System.out.println( fib );

      }


    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It's always a good idea to indent your code, so that you and others can understand it better.

Comment: ok,ill do that from now on, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution for 2nd question Just Type **System.out.println( fib );** outside the loop. So it will directly show the final value of fib. I can't understand your 1st question !

Initialize fib ( int fib = 0 ) you can also declare variable withing the for loop. so don't need to declare i before for loop. just declare it inside the for loop like

```
for (int i=2; i<n; i++)  
{  
    fib=f1+f2;  
    f1=f2;  
    f2=fib;  
}  

System.out.println( fib );
```

> **Complete Code**

```
import java.util.Scanner;  
public class fibs  
{  
 public static void main(String[] args)  
 {  
  Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in); // readying keyboard for input  
  int f1, f2, n, fib = 0;  
  System.out.println("Please enter a vaule for F(1):");  
  f1 = keyboard.nextInt();  
  System.out.println("Please enter a vaule for F(2):");  
  f2 = keyboard.nextInt();  
  System.out.println("Please enter a vaule for n :");  
  n = keyboard.nextInt();  

  if ((f1<0)||(f2<0)||(f1>1000)||(f2>1000)||(n<1))  
  {  
   System.out.println("Please try again");  
   return;  
  }  
  else  
  {  
   for (int i=2; i<n; i++)  
   {  
    fib=f1+f2;  
    f1=f2;  
    f2=fib;        
   }
   System.out.println( fib );  
  }  
 }  
}
```

Comment: ok, when i do that i get error: variable fib might not have been initialized
System.out.println( fib );          1st question was , if the user enter f1 and f2, i want the program to count them as first two terms in the series, but it doesnt

Comment: You should initialized when you declare the variable at int fib=0;

Answer (score 0):

1) start your loop at 2:

```
for (i=2; i<n; i++)
```

2) put the call to println() outside of the loop.

```
for (i=2; i<n; i++)  
{  
    fib=f1+f2;  
    f1=f2;  
    f2=fib;  
}
System.out.println(fib);
```

Comment: ok, so for  1) when i try to run the program, the same thing happens, and for 2) when i put it out side i get the error: variable fib might not have been initialized
System.out.println( fib );